# Laravel Sanctum Nuxt User Registration Error

Tags: laravel, nuxt.js, laravel-sanctum

I have a Laravel API and I implemented authentication with Laravel Sanctum and I am using `homestead`. I am trying to connect my Nuxt SSR frontend. Currently, I am experiencing an issue that I don't seem to understand and I have searched but can see any similar issue anyway.

The issue is that I can't even register a user from my Nuxt application. I get `CSRF token mismatch` error when I make a request to the register route.

- API domain: `api.myapp.test`
- Frontend domain: `myapp.test:3000`

Sending a POST request to `http://api.myapp.test/v1/register` return a `CSRF token mismatch` error.

Is there something I am not getting right?

#### Below are my Laravel configs:

`cors.php`

```php
return [
    'paths' => ['v1/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,

];
```

`session.php`

```php
[
   'domain' => '.myapp.test',
]
```

`sanctum.php`

```php
return [
    'stateful' => [
        'myapp.test:3000', 'api.myapp.test'
    ],

];
```

I am using nuxt/axios in my frontend.
`nuxt.config.js`

```js
{
// Even if I remove the credentials property, is still does not work
  axios: {
    credentials: true
  },
}
```

I am really confused because I don't get the error when I make the same request from **Postman**.

Answer (score 0):

I propose you to use @nuxt/auth-module it has build in strategy for Laravel Sanctum. And as mentioned in docs:

> NOTE: It is highly recommended to use proxy to avoid CORS and same-site policy issues:

```
{
  axios: {
    proxy: true,
    credentials: true
  },
  proxy: {
    '/laravel': {
      target: 'https://laravel-auth.nuxtjs.app',
      pathRewrite: { '^/laravel': '/' }
    }
  },
  auth: {
    strategies: {
      'laravelSanctum': {
        provider: 'laravel/sanctum',
        url: '<laravel url>'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then after manual registration through your controller, you can login user immediately using:

```
this.$auth.loginWith('laravelSanctum', {
  data: {
    email: '',
    password: ''
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks @gluktd. Maybe I forgot to mention it. The login is working fine. However, when I make a request to any other routes it returns the `CSRF token mismatch` error.

As mention in my question, If I try to register a new user, the returns the  error

Comment: Add please your Login and Register Controller

Comment: Okay. I tried to, first, make a get request to the `/sanctum/csrf-cookie` endpoint before sending the request to the `/register` endpoint and it works. If I make the post request to the `/register` endpoint without first making a GET request to the `/sanctum/csrf-cookie` I get the `CSRF token mismatch` error.

Now my concern is whether this is the way it is supposed to be?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this instead writing the get axios for csrf cookie manually?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear from your question wether or not you're calling the necessary `'/sanctum/csrf-cookie'` endpoint before you're attempting to call your registration end point. If you're not, great news— the fix is really simple! Just send a `GET` request to the csrf cookie end point before attempting the others, and you should find your CSRF errors resolve.

Docs here:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#csrf-protection

EDIT: Postman works, because CORS is a browser based protocol. Postman isn't a browser, and doesn't care at all if the server responds with or without the otherwise appropriate CORS headers.

Comment: My confusion is that the documentation mentioned only logging a user into the application. It was not clear that one should do the same when registering a user.